# Повторное выполнение функции описанной в диалоговом JqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

У меня есть всплывающая форма в которой автоматом генерятся кнопки.
Когда форма закрывается все поля в ней чистятся.

```
     function closeDialog() {
            componets_array_ID =[];
            varButton = [];
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $(".getInputComponent").val('');
            $(".prodName").val('');
            $(".prodProvider").val('');
            $(".prodCode").val('');
            $(".selectCategory").find('option').remove();
            if($(".dialog_create_product").dialog("isOpen")){
                $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("destroy")
            };
        }
```

После того как окно открывается второй раз генерируемая кнопка при нажатии обрабатывается дважды. Если окно закрыть и открыть третий раз то кнопка обрабатывается трижды...и так далее.

Вот все полотно если надо:

```
 open: function (event, ui) {
                            //формируем select
                            $.ajax({ url: "/ButtonServlet",
                                data: {
                                    getCategory : "getCategory",
                                },
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType:'json',
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                                        $('.selectCategory').append($("<option></option>")
                                                .attr("value",element[0])
                                                .text(element[1]));
                                    })
                                    fillCompound($(".selectCategory").val())
                                },
                                error: function(request, status, error){
                                    alert("Error: Could not back");
                                }
                            });
                            //определяем выбранный select и заполняем кнопки
                            $(".selectCategory").change(function (){
                                var selId;
                                $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
                                    selId = $( this ).val()
                                });
                                fillCompound(selId)
                            });
                            //ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ ПОВТОРНО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            //обработка кнопок
                            $(".compound").on("click", ".btnCompound", function () {
                                $(".components").append($(this));
                                componets_array_ID.push($(this).attr("id"));


                            });
                            //ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ ПОВТОРНО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            $(".components").on("click", ".btnCompound", function () {
                                $(".compound").append($(this));
                                comp_index = componets_array_ID.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));
                                if (comp_index > -1) {
                                    componets_array_ID.splice(comp_index, 1);
                                }
                                alert("вызов2")
                            });

                            $(".components").on("click", ".varButton", function () {
                                $(this).remove();
                                varBtn_index = varButton.indexOf($(this).text());
                                if (comp_index > -1) {
                                    varButton.splice(varBtn_index, 1);
                                }
                            });
                            $(".divInput").on("click", ".addComponent", function () {
                                if ($(".getInputComponent").val() != ""){
                                    $(".components").append("<button class=\"varButton\">"+$(".getInputComponent").val()+"</button>");
                                    varButton.push($(".getInputComponent").val());
                                    $(".getInputComponent").val('');
                                }
                            })
                        },
```

Comment: при каждом выполнении обработчика `open` Вы назначаете новые/дополнительные обработчики `click`. Вынесите последние из `open`  в `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Игорь, все верно. Спасибо. Дайте ответ(а не комментарий), чтобы я мог проголосовать за него как за правильный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При каждом выполнении обработчика `open` Вы назначаете новые/дополнительные обработчики `click`. Вынесите последние из `open` в `$(document).ready`.

*Update (по пунктам):*

1. `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` - глобальная (для страницы) установка одной из опций `$.ajax`, не влияет на обработчики событий, назначенные элементам DOM.
2. `$(".dialog_create_product").dialog("destroy")` - http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy :

> Removes the dialog functionality completely. This will return the
>   element back to its pre-init state.

тоже к обработчикам событий, назначенных Вашим кодом, отношения не имеет.

3. Если элементы, выбранные селекторами `$(".selectCategory")`, `$(".compound")`, `$(".components")` и `$(".divInput")`, продолжают жить (т.е. не удаляются и не создаются вновь на открытие диалога), то обработчики события `click` для них будут накапливаться при повторных выполнениях `open`.

Comment: Если не сложно. Я не особо силен в juqery, а темболее в жизненном цикле его объектов, но разве `$(".dialog_create_product").dialog("destroy")` или `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` не дожны были убить предыдущие обработчики?