# JqueryUI - Dialog многократно открывается

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Так вроде диалог открывается и закрывается нормально.
Но проблема возникает когда я повторно нажимаю `#btn3`.
После этого после открытия диалога с помощью `#button_create_product` диалог дублируется столько раз сколько был нажат `#btn3`
`button_create_product` описан в `products.jsp`

```
   $('#btn3').click(function () {
            $('#menu').load("products.jsp",function () {
                $('#button_create_product').click( function() {
                    $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');

                });
                $( ".dialog_create_product" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        OK: function() {
                            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")

                        },
                        CANSEL: function() {
                            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: мы же вчера разобрались с такой же проблемой (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571800):  Вынесите назначение `$('#button_create_product').click` в `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Да, Игорь, спасибо. Было дело. Я пробовал но у меня не получается обработать эту кнопку из `$(document).ready`. Не кликается...и так тоже  `$('.div_dialog_create_product').on("click", ".button_create_product", function() {
                $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');`

Comment: Разобрался, не правильно вынес. надо ` $(document).on("click", ".button_create_product", function ()` теперь кнопка работает из корня `$(document).ready` но результат не изменился.

Comment: Богдан, мне кажется (и я, конечно, могу ошибаться), что у Вас неправильное вложение назначений событий друг в друга. Сколько раз за время жизни страницы должно загружаться `$('#menu')`? Нужно ли инициализировать диалог `$(".dialog_create_product").dialog` внутри обработчика `load`? Элемент `".dialog_create_product"` существует вне элемента `'#menu'` или внутри него?

Comment: Я думаю вы правы но как найти косяк я не знаю. Вообще, `menu` это тело нижней части страницы где отражаются разные `html` по клику '#btn1','#btn2','#btn3'. Я не знаю где лучше инициализировать диалог. Я хотел сделать все крассиво. Чтобы в методе каждой кнопки меню . `$('#btn').click(function (){$('#menu').load("products.jsp...` загружалась нужная страница и в этом же методе обявлял все переменные и меоды которые используются на этой странице(метод с кучей методов, переменных, "кнопок"). Но мне начинает казаться что такая архетектура в корне не верна....

Comment: Я больше по JAVA и ООП не привык к такому полотну и думал создать что-то типа основого объекта(тут это метод) и инкапсулировать туда все аспекты поведения. Чтобы комфортней было и читаьильней

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, вы нажимаете несколько раз на кнопку и каждый раз по ней вызывается функция. Не плохо было бы блокировать до того момента, пока не придёт ответ от сервера отключать кнопку. Примерно так:

```
var myBtn = $('#btn3') // Ну просто, чтоб её по 10 раз не искать.
myBtn.click(function () {
    myBtn.attr('disabled', 1) // Мгновенно заблокировали кнопку
    $('#menu').load('products.jsp', function() {
        myBtn.removeAttr('disabled') // А раз получили результат, разблокируем
        $('#button_create_product').click(function() {
            $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');
        });
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

Comment: Интерестная идя+

Comment: Но пользы от нее нет )

Comment: Спасибо. Вообщем пока выкрутился по вашему. При нажатии на '#btn3' блокирую эту кнопку. А при нажатии на  '#btn1','#btn2'... восстанавливаю...Костыль вообщем(

Comment: А фиг там все равно лагает )

Comment: @bogdan-shulga не стоило придумывать этот костыль. Кнопку лучше восстанавливать при получении ответа сервера, как я показал в ответе. Это может быть фейл промиса, может быть отрицательный ответ самой страницы, при любом ичходе, надо оживлять кнопку обратно.

Comment: Уточните что лагает?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `$('#button_create_product').unbind("click");` прежде чем навесить на это событие новую функцию. Иначе будет срабатывать каждая добавленная функция.

Comment: То есть использовать эту конструкцию перед `$('#button_create_product').click( function()...` если да то тогда это не помогло

Comment: Какой-то вредный совет, если честно. Неужели вы хотите лишить возможности дважды открыть диалог?